# findByDate returning documents from previous day

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to fetch a list of objects by date, but the resulted list is always of the day before.

```
@GetMapping("date")
ResponseEntity findByDate(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date) {
        log.info("date is: "+date);
        log.info("Delfaul time zone is: "+ TimeZone.getDefault());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(consumptionService.findByDate(date));
    }
```

the controller calls the service, which calls HourlyConsumptionRepo:

```
public interface HourlyConsumptionRepo extends MongoRepository<HourlyConsumption, ObjectId> {
    List<HourlyConsumption> findByDate(Date date);
}
```

[Postman results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIALO.png)

[Postman results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC21c.png)

I think it might be an issue of timezones, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses UTC times by default. See here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/. So those results are "valid", I'm assuming you are UTC+2.